# What flavors would you like to see for our weekly flavor days?

Tags: discussion, events

Currently we have a weekly event on Saturdays in order to encourage users to come and as question of a specific flavor. It's easier to participate when you have a topic to narrow things down.

[So far we've done the following flavors](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/539/what-flavors-have-already-been-featured-in-flavor-day):

- "Cats" (and cat-related things)
- "Small" and "cute"
- "Games" and "sports"
- "Music"
- "80-90s Classics"
- "Swimming" and "Beaches"
- "Shoujo" and/or "romance"
- "Parodies" and "Cross-references"

**Flavors can be used more than once**, so if you want to do a flavor that's been done before, feel free to upvote it again if you would like the flavor done again!

If you have a new flavor you'd like to suggest, feel free to post it here. Nothing is off-limits, but lets try to keep things kosher. **Answers with at least 3 upvotes will be considered.**

**In the event of a tie, whichever answer is older will be chosen** (unless anyone has a better suggestion for how to break ties).

Some suggestions to follow:

- Try not to be be too abstract. Given users a better idea of the theme. "Swimming" and "beaches" are fine, but "cold" and "sweet" might be a bit vague.
- One flavor is fine , but two usually is better, in cause someone is not interested in one, they can do the other. Try to have some relation between the two flavors. E.g. for "small" and "cute," small things are usually cute.
- Try to include a brief of why you choose your flavor(s) so other ppl will know what to expect. E.g., I propose "food" and "shopping" because I'd like to see more questions about cooking anime/manga.
- Have fun~

Use this template for your suggestion(s), **one suggestion per answer please**:

> **Flavor(s)**: "Flavor 1" and/or "flavor 2"
>
> **Description**: (What sort of things you are looking for?)

Answer (score 6):

## This flavor was chosen for May 11, 2013

**Flavor**: Music (including OP and ED sequences)

**Description**: Anything related to anime about music, or music in anime (such as theme songs).

Almost all anime have theme songs, and most have a lot more music in their OSTs than just that. As such, it's something that fans of many different genres can ask about. Also, shows about music, like Nodame Cantabile and Beck, don't seem to be getting many questions, so this could potentially help generate a few.

Comment: How about cramming in opening and ending animation sequences? They tend to have some interesting and hidden things related the show's story.

Comment: @user1306322 That was my original intent. I'll edit it to be clearer though.

Answer (score 5):

## This flavor was chosen for May 25, 2013

**Flavors:** "Swimming" and/or "Beaches"

**Description:** Anything related to girls and guys swimming (indoors or outdoors), or participating in beach sports or events (like beach volleyball, suntanning, etc.).

This was one of the themes that didn't make the cut this week, but I still think it has lots of potential without being too broad; plus, who doesn't love beach scenes?

Comment: You just want to see characters in skimpy swimming outfits don't you?

Comment: @Krazer Don't tell me you don't want to!

Comment: This flavor was rather bland D:

Comment: @Krazer Indeed... I guess you really just can't argue with babes in swimsuits.

Answer (score 5):

**Flavor:** Dreams and Illusions

**Description:** Any questions relating to the meaning of dreams, illusions, or hallucinations in anime or manga.

There are a lot of anime with dreams or illusions playing an important part.  Sometimes it can be really confusing for a Western audience who don't understand the imagery that takes place in them.

Answer (score 5):

## This flavor was chosen for May 18, 2013

**Flavors:** <s>80's/early 90's OVAs and/or "Classics"</s> "80-90s Classics"

**Description:** In the 80's and early 90's, generally known for the "OVA boom" filled with some really high quality productions (and sometimes remarkably bad) of OVAs that were no longer than 2 or 3 episodes. Questions about OVAs from this era, like Amon Saga, Cosmos Pink Shock, Baoh, Earthian, Angel Cop, Bounty Dog, Judge, Roots Search, etc.

Or, questions about the OVAs, movies, and TV series from the early 90's or older: Space Battleship Yamato, Galaxy Express 999, Future Boy Conan, Fist of the Northstar, Touch, Maison Ikkoku, Mobile Suit Gundam, SDF Macross, etc.

Answer (score 5):

## This flavor was chosen for June 15, 2013

**Flavors:** "Parodies" and "cross-references"

**Description:** Question about the parodies and references in anime/manga/light novels, of real life events, other anime/manga/light novels. For example, *Sayonara Zetsubou Sensei*, *Hayate no Gotoku*, *Haiyore! Nyaruko-san*, *Joshiraku*, ... makes a large number of parodies and references to real life event happening at the time of publication and old anime/manga.

Answer (score 5):

**Flavors:** Imoutos (little sisters) and/or Tsundere characters

**Description:** Two of the most common moe archetypes. Tsundere gained a lot of popularity last decade, and are still going strong today. Little sisters aren't new, but in the past few years there have been a large number of shows focused on younger sisters (a so-called "imouto boom"). Plus, little sisters have existed since the beginning of time, so there are plenty of examples to work with even if you aren't following recent anime.

Given that there are plenty of tsundere imoutos, it makes sense to put them together.

Comment: Can't stop thinking about BioShock. Little sisters everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

## This flavor was chosen for June 1, 2013

**Flavors:** Shoujo and/or romance

**Description:** Questions about shoujo series, or the romance aspects of any series.

I've seen a lot of questions about shounen series, but not nearly as many as its female counterpart. It would be nice to see more though.

Answer (score 4):

**Flavors:** "Allegory" and "Symbolism"

**Description:** A lot of series tend to hide deeper behind opject or story telling that are not immediately obvious or are missed the first time around. I'd like to invite ppl to revisit and re-examine potentional plot points and connections that they may have missed or the tropes related to them. E.g. the cave allegory in the *Ghost in the Shell* series; Apples in certain anime.

Answer (score 4):

**Flavors**: Winter and/or Christmas

**Description:** Many anime have winter themed episodes, and Christmas specials are also not uncommon. Related things, like snow, winter sports, etc. are also welcome.

[This forum post](http://forums.animesuki.com/showthread.php?p=3403490#post3403490) has a list of about 100 anime with Christmas themed episodes from over 2 years ago. I don't have a more complete list, but it should at least convince you that this is very common in anime and hopefully give you ideas for questions.

Comment: Why not include holidays in general? New year episode are usually pretty big in animus, too? Not to mention Valentine's and White Day.

Comment: @Krazer Expanding to all holidays feels too disjoint to me, and I think having a topic that is too broad actually makes it harder to come up with questions. Valentines day and New years could also be nominated separately, but IMO it's better if we don't combine all of them into one.

Answer (score 3):

**Flavors:** "Robots" and/or "Monsters/Aliens"

**Description:** Question about your robots (giant, life-size, or miniature, there's not enough questions about robots and mechs), technology (why is Ichika the only male IS pilot?), mechanics ([anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics)? How do Lucy's vectors work in Elfen Lied), and monster/aliens physiology (Human-Zentraedi relations), motives/politics (in MaouYuu, how are demon lords chosen), and battles/action scenes involving them.

I'd like to highlight some of our existing series tags involving these topics promote more questions of those tags. More robots/mecha, more power!

Answer (score 3):

**Flavors:** "Pets" or [specific type of pet]

**Description:** We did **cats** why not do other pets or familiars?

Comment: Because cats are clearly superior!

Answer (score 1):

**Flavours:** "Space" or "Foreign lands"

**Description:** Questions about anime that are located outside Japan, or even outside Earth! Could deal with stereotypical views of foreigners, alien contact, School Trips, etc. I'd imagine it should be a broad enough range to fit various interesting questions in.

Answer (score 1):

***Flavours:*** Powers or Super-human abilities

***Description:*** Ask about how why the Kyuubi has so much Chakara, How laser eyes work, How do these shounen characters keep getting back up?!
A lot of questions here seem to be somewhat shounen-y, so a topic like this might encourage more users to participate.

*Note: I guess this is somewhat like @Krazer 's answer for mech, but it's a bit more specific*

Answer (score 1):

***Flavours:*** "Partners" or "Duos"

***Description:***  Questions about couples, heroes and sidekicks, Siblings, Companions... Any group of two anime characters.

We haven't had that many questions about character's relationships (that I could see), might draw some good ones out.