# What flavors have already been featured in "Flavor Day"?

Tags: discussion, statistics, events

We've been promoting an event that takes place every Saturday: "**Flavor Day**".
In each Flavor Day, one or two flavors are picked and questions about them are encouraged (for further info and suggestions for flavors you'd like to see featured, see [this post](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/537/what-flavors-would-you-like-to-see-for-our-weekly-flavor-days)).

This post's purpose is to keep track of the questions asked each week under each "flavor".
**Each answer left here will correspond to a Flavor Day**, meaning there will be one answer per week.

Use this template for each week:

> **Flavor Day #**
>   **Flavor(s)**: "Flavor 1" and/or "flavor 2"
>   **Date**: Date of the flavor in question
>
> - **Question 1**
> - **Question 2**
> - ...
> - **Question n**
>
> **Total**: n questions

---

Comment: who decides on what flavors are used?

Comment: The flavors are proposed on [this post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/537/what-flavors-would-you-like-to-see-for-our-weekly-flavor-days) or in chat, and so far the decision has been made in chat by whoever participates in the discussion. So far me, Krazer, LoganM and Eric have been deciding it, but very few people other than us have been participating in the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

**Flavor Day 7**
**Flavor**: "Shoujo" and/or "Romance"
**Date**: June 1, 2013

- [**Why does Li hate Mizuki?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/why-does-li-hate-mizuki)
- [**How many endings are there in the School Days Visual Novel?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/how-many-endings-are-there-in-the-school-days-visual-novel)
- [**Is there any more meaning to Ren's name?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3988/is-there-any-more-meaning-to-rens-name)
- [**How closely does the La Corda d'Oro manga follow the game?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3990/how-closely-does-the-la-corda-doro-manga-follow-the-game)
- [**Why does Usui wear glasses at home?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3992/why-does-usui-wear-glasses-at-home)
- [**What is the text before the OP in episode 9 talking about?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3994/what-is-the-text-before-the-op-in-episode-9-talking-about)

**Total**: 6 questions

Answer (score 0):

**Flavor Day 3**
**Flavors**: "Games" and "Sports"
**Date**: May 4, 2013

- [**Is Subaru ever caught in the vault?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/is-subaru-ever-caught-in-the-vault)
- [**Is there a difference between BFB and Basquash?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3658/is-there-a-difference-between-bfb-and-basquash)
- [**What prizes are awarded during the Daihasei Festival?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3659/what-prizes-are-awarded-during-the-daihasei-festival)
- [**Why did the Slam Dunk anime stop without animating the Interhigh tournament?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3665/why-did-the-slam-dunk-anime-stop-without-animating-the-interhigh-tournament)
- [**What ruleset is used for the Prefecture and National tournaments?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3663/what-ruleset-is-used-for-the-prefecture-and-national-tournaments)
- [**How does Faye actually gamble away all of her money?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/how-does-faye-actually-gamble-away-all-of-her-money)
- [**Who are the members of the Lyacons?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3662/who-are-the-members-of-the-lyacons)
- [**What game are António, Carlos and Jobim playing?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/what-game-are-antonio-carlos-and-jobim-playing)
- [**What caused the shift in the world after the climax of the show?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3670/what-caused-the-shift-in-the-world-after-the-climax-of-the-show)
- [**What is happening in the “Depth of Field” specials?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3673/what-is-happening-in-the-depth-of-field-specials)
- [**Does Kanon enjoy figure skating?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3674/does-kanon-enjoy-figure-skating)
- [**What is the card game the characters play?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3675/what-is-the-card-game-the-characters-play)

**Total**: 12 questions

Answer (score 0):

**Flavor Day 2**
**Flavors**: "Small" and "Cute"
**Date**: April 27, 2013

- [**When does Hina learn that her parents died?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3591/when-does-hina-learn-that-her-parents-died)
- [**When does Kud Wafter fit into the story?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3590/when-does-kud-wafter-fit-into-the-story)
- [**Why is Ana embarrassed by her surname?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3589/why-is-ana-embarrassed-by-her-surname)
- [**When do succubi mature?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/when-do-succubi-mature)
- [**How do Konoha's powers work?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/how-do-konohas-powers-work)
- [**Does Nao ever realize that Pastel Ink is Ink?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3584/does-nao-ever-realize-that-pastel-ink-is-ink)
- [**When do the Kodomo no Jikan OVA side stories take place?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3582/when-do-the-kodomo-no-jikan-ova-side-stories-take-place)
- [**Is Ika Musume the only humanoid squid creature?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3580/is-ika-musume-the-only-humanoid-squid-creature)
- [**What is the chibi-esque gathering at the end of each episode?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/what-is-the-chibi-esque-gathering-at-the-end-of-each-episode)
- [**What game is Subaru playing with the girls?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-game-is-subaru-playing-with-the-girls)
- [**Is Kamineko a jerk?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3566/is-kamineko-a-jerk)
- [**What kind of creature is Chiyo-chichi?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3567/what-kind-of-creature-is-chiyo-chichi)
- [**What is the intended purpose of Haro?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3565/what-is-the-intended-purpose-of-haro)
- [**What is the fate of Densuke at the end of the last episode?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/what-is-the-fate-of-densuke-at-the-end-of-the-last-episode)
- [**How much does the anime differ from the light novels?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3559/how-much-does-the-anime-differ-from-the-light-novels)
- [**Who is the boy in the coffin in the last episode (of the Gemini of the Meteor)?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3562/who-is-the-boy-in-the-coffin-in-the-last-episode-of-the-gemini-of-the-meteor)
- [**What are all of Rin's cats that have names?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3557/what-are-all-of-rins-cats-that-have-names)
- [**What happened to Aura between the events of G.U. and the movie?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/what-happened-to-aura-between-the-events-of-g-u-and-the-movie)
- [**What is the significance of the title “Ro-Kyu-Bu!”?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3555/what-is-the-significance-of-the-title-ro-kyu-bu)
- [**Does the “flower's name” myth have a real-world basis?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3524/does-the-flowers-name-myth-have-a-real-world-basis)
- [**What causes the robots to develop sentience?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3548/what-causes-the-robots-to-develop-sentience)

**Total**: 21 questions

Answer (score 0):

**Flavor Day 1**
**Flavor**: "Cats" (and cat-related stuff)
**Date**: April 20, 2013

- [**Was Chiyo's real father ever shown?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/was-chiyos-real-father-ever-shown)
- [**Is “The Melancholy of Momoneko-sama” based on any legends?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/is-the-melancholy-of-momoneko-sama-based-on-any-legends)
- [**What species is Pannya?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3471/what-species-is-pannya)
- [**Why is Train Heartnet called Black Cat?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3468/why-is-train-heartnet-called-black-cat)
- [**Were Luna and Artemis the only (sentient) cats in Sailor Moon?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/were-luna-and-artemis-the-only-sentient-cats-in-sailor-moon)
- [**What is the name of Misaka 10032's cat?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/what-is-the-name-of-misaka-10032s-cat)
- [**Why is Nyanko-sensei a round, chubby cat?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3459/why-is-nyanko-sensei-a-round-chubby-cat)
- [**What is the significance of the black cat?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/what-is-the-significance-of-the-black-cat)
- [**What animals and confections are each of the characters?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/what-animals-and-confections-are-each-of-the-characters)
- [**How can Sakamoto talk?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3454/how-can-sakamoto-talk)
- [**Why is Poyo completely round?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3453/why-is-poyo-completely-round)
- [**How many siblings does Tonnura have?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3452/how-many-siblings-does-tonnura-have)

**Total**: 12 questions

Answer (score 0):

**Flavor Day 4**
**Flavor**: "Music" (including OP and ED sequences)
**Date**: May 11, 2013

- [**How are the themes and songs picked for a particular series?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3744/how-are-the-themes-and-songs-picked-for-a-particular-series)
- [**How does Jigglypuff not fall asleep from it's own song?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3743/how-does-jigglypuff-not-fall-asleep-from-its-own-song)
- [**Is there any meaning to the first Hatsuyuki Sakura OP “freak of nature: start”?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3745/is-there-any-meaning-to-the-first-hatsuyuki-sakura-op-freak-of-nature-start)
- [**Can Chiaki play any instruments besides violin and piano?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3746/can-chiaki-play-any-instruments-besides-violin-and-piano)
- [**What's the deal with all the crabs in the Aiura OP?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3749/whats-the-deal-with-all-the-crabs-in-the-aiura-op)
- [**Are there bands specifically dedicated to anime?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3750/are-there-bands-specifically-dedicated-to-anime)
- [**What is the significance of the “A in C major” note the occurs whenever there is a strange event in The World?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3753/why-does-the-a-in-c-major-tone-plays-whenever-a-strange-event-occurs-in-the-wo)
- [**At the end of the last episode, does everyone retain their old memories?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/at-the-end-of-the-last-episode-does-everyone-retain-their-old-memories)
- [**Are the members of Beck based on real life musicians?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3751/are-the-members-of-beck-based-on-real-life-musicians)
- [**Was there ever an a cappella version of Nemurihime released?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3752/was-there-ever-an-a-cappella-version-of-nemurihime-released)
- [**What pieces were adapted for the soundtrack of G-senjou no Maou?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3754/what-pieces-were-adapted-for-the-soundtrack-of-g-senjou-no-maou)
- [**Vocaloid in anime soundtracks**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3760/vocaloid-in-anime-soundtracks)
- [**List of anime with correct animation of the characters playing musical instrument**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3758/list-of-anime-with-correct-animation-of-the-characters-playing-musical-instrumen)

**Total**: 13 questions

Answer (score 0):

**Flavor Day 5**
**Flavor**: "80-90s Classics"
**Date**: April 18, 2013

- [**What happened to the last two Bastard!! OVAs?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3806/what-happened-to-the-last-two-bastard-ovas)
- [**Why were most of the players' names changed in the dubs?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/why-were-most-of-the-players-names-changed-in-the-dubs)
- [**What is the OVA boom?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/what-is-the-ova-boom)
- [**What are the notable differences between Hunter x Hunter in 1999 vs 2011?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3812/what-are-the-notable-differences-between-hunter-x-hunter-in-1999-vs-2011)
- [**Why does Tetsuo say “I am Tetsuo” at the end of Akira?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/why-does-tetsuo-say-i-am-tetsuo-at-the-end-of-akira)
- [**Is Akira the only anime produced in 24fps?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/is-akira-the-only-anime-produced-in-24fps)
- [**Why is the name “Harkonnen” used on Seras' cannon in Hellsing?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/why-is-the-name-harkonnen-used-on-seras-cannon-in-hellsing)
- [**What is Lupin III's nationality?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3816/what-is-lupin-iiis-nationality)
- [**Why is Gally's name localized as Alita?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3817/why-is-gallys-name-localized-as-alita)
- [**Was “Snow Rondo” all a dream or was there something more to it?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3819/was-snow-rondo-all-a-dream-or-was-there-something-more-to-it)
- [**What factors contributed the “golden age” of anime?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/what-factors-contributed-the-golden-age-of-anime)
- [**What are the “tentacles” coming out of people's heads?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3824/what-are-the-tentacles-coming-out-of-peoples-heads)
- [**Why does Mika go insane?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3827/why-does-mika-go-insane)
- [**What was the first mecha anime/manga to feature combining to form a super robot?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/what-was-the-first-mecha-anime-manga-to-feature-combining-to-form-a-super-robot)
- [**How did the Chris gain the power of Garzey's Wing?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/how-did-the-chris-gain-the-power-of-garzeys-wing)
- [**Where does the Future Boy Conan movie fit in?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3829/where-does-the-future-boy-conan-movie-fit-in)
- [**Where did the other survivors come from?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3830/where-did-the-other-survivors-come-from)
- [**Protagonist saves the world by killing monsters by transforming into different mecha using disks**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/protagonist-saves-the-world-by-killing-monsters-by-transforming-into-different-m)

**Total**: 18 questions

Answer (score 0):

**Flavor Day 6**
**Flavor**: "Swimming" and "Beaches"
**Date**: April 25, 2013

- [**How was the Dai-Gurren improved in episode 12?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3902/how-was-the-dai-gurren-improved-in-episode-12)
- [**Why are there holes in the ocean?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3905/why-are-there-holes-in-the-ocean)
- [**What is the purpose of the watermelon in the ritual at the beach?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-watermelon-in-the-ritual-at-the-beach)
- [**Why did Yukari's father wander off on his honeymoon?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3908/why-did-yukaris-father-wander-off-on-his-honeymoon)
- [**What is the actual dialog for this Death Note swimming meme?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3909/what-is-the-actual-dialog-for-this-death-note-swimming-meme)
- [**Why didn't Yokodera send Azuki Azusa back to Okinawa?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/why-didnt-yokodera-send-azuki-azusa-back-to-okinawa)
- [**What is the name of the name tag found on certain swimsuits?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3913/what-is-the-name-of-the-name-tag-found-on-certain-swimsuits)

**Total**: 7 questions

Answer (score 0):

**Flavor Day 8**
**Flavors**: "Parodies" and "Cross-references"
**Date**: June 15, 2013

- [**What is the relation between the flowers and the heroines in ED sequence of Photokano?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/what-is-the-relation-between-the-flowers-and-the-heroines-in-ed-sequence-of-phot)
- [**What are all the cross-references in Binbo Gami Ga?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/what-are-all-the-cross-references-in-binbo-gami-ga)
- [**Who are these characters referenced in chapter 4 of Spotted Flower?**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4127/who-are-these-characters-referenced-in-chapter-4-of-spotted-flower)